# Prevent dependencies between certain modules in Python (static analysis)

Tags: python, static-analysis

I have a Python app (Django, if you're curious). We do some minor static analysis (flake8, black formatting), but I'd like to prevent certain dependencies from creeping in. I want to prevent certain modules from importing other modules (e.g. I'd like to be able to specify a rule that `users/models.py` shouldn't depend on `comments/*` or something like that.

Couldn't find any documentation with static analysis tools like pylint, etc.